# Should there be data in a relationship table(Many-to-Many) or should it be in a separate table?

Tags: mysql, sql

Should data be separated from a relationship table.

[image: Relationship table without data]

Or should data be within the relationship table?

[image: Relationship table with data]

Small side question: If there will only ever be `1 user per stock`. Should I rather use a `composite key` as the `primary key` in the `user_stock` table?

Comment: Depends on how you are going to use it, but I would recommend the second.

Comment: Note that in the second example, iduser_stock is redundant

Comment: @Strawberry, Incorrect in this case `iduser_stock` is an autoincrement. Not a composite key, please see `small side question`

Comment: No. Correct. You have a perfectly valid natural composite key that can serve as primary

Comment: @Strawberry, Incorrect. As I stated in this case the `iduser_stock` is an autoincremented primary key, if a composite key is valid you may state that and I may approve. There is however, the issue of selecting all `user_stock` records where the `userid` is say `1`. Now we can't do that with a composite key, can we?

Comment: Of course we can. What are you talking about?

Comment: @StevieG: Sure you can select on both keys! what you probla think/mean is: that de index is created on (user:id,Stock:id) so you should create an extra on for (Stock:id)

Answer (score 0):

It should not be a relationship table.. User stock table will act as a master table.. 
The composite key should be created for user_Id and stock id as user _id will not be unique in the transaction table